# erand48 windows equivalent

Tags: visual-c++, random

I am looking for the windows equivalent of erand48. In my code, I have the line:
`erand48(u.us);`
and it gives the error error C3861: 'erand48': identifier not found. I found that this is because erand48 is used in Unix and not in Windows. I believe it generates a random number within some range, but I am having trouble finding out for sure. Does anyone know what the best way to address this is? I am using windows Visual Studios to port multiple projects from Unix to Visual C++.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description, [erand48](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_erand48.htm), is a 48 bit RNG returning a double.  I don't know VC++ well enough to know if it reproduces erand48's use of its parameter to store working values.  It should not be too difficult to write the code yourself, given that the reference supplies the outline.

Comment: Awesome! I will give writing it a shot! I am very new to C++, but this seems like something I can handle. Thanks!